# Sum of all vectors in a vector space over a finite field

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-writing, finite-fields

Let $F_n$ be a finite field of $n$ elements, where $n$ is a power of a prime.

Now, let $F_n^k$ be the set of all row vectors of length $k$ over $F_n$.

Is it true that the sum of all of the none zero vectors is equal to the zero vector?

I have experimented with small cases and this seems to be true, but I can’t prove the general result?

Comment: What about $n=2$, $k=1$?

Comment: Clearly it is false in that case. How about for $k \geq 2$?

Comment: If $n>2$ is a power of prime, then the sum is $0$.  If $n=2$ and $k>1$, the sum is also $0$.  The idea is to simply show that each coordinate at a given value is counted $n^{k-1}$ times in the sum.  For $n>2$ and $k=1$, use the fact that the sum of the elements of $F_n$ is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of all vectors $s = \sum_{x \in F_n^k} x$ is $\operatorname{GL}_k(F_n)$-invariant, i.e. for every $A \in \operatorname{GL}_k(F_n)$ we have that $As = s$.
For any two non-zero vectors $x, y \in F_n^k$ there exists some $A \in \operatorname{GL}_k(F_n)$ with $Ax = y$, so if $F_n^k$ contains at least three elements then it follows that $s = 0$.
If $F_n^k$ has at most two elements than either $k = 0$, in which case $s = 0$, or $F_n = F_2$ and $k = 1$, in which case $s = 1$ (where we identitfy $F_2^1$ with $F_2$).

Answer (score 0):

It is true. Suppose $n$ is not a power of 2. There are $n$ possible first entries for a vector. Note, the sum of all $n$ elements in the finite field is $0$ when $n$ isn't a power of $2$. Further, for each choice of a first entry, except $0$, there are the same number of non-zero vectors with this first entry. Thus, the sum of all the non-zero vectors will have first entry equal to $0$. The same logic shows the other entries will also sum to $0$.

If $n$ is a power of $2$ and $k>1$, there will be $n^{k-1}$ vectors with a given non-zero first entry. This is because there are $n$ choices for every other entry. The result follows once one multiplies the first entry by $n^{k-1}$.

If $k=1$ and $n$ is a power of $2$, then the result doesn't hold.

Comment: That was my first reaction. But no, the sum of all the elements of a finite field  need not be $0$. Consider $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: I suppose the case where the characteristic is 2 needs to be treated separately.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich:  but won't it be true if $\text{char}(F_n) \ne 2$?  Then $F_n$ has an even number of non-zero elements, and we can pair each with it's inverse . . .

Comment: Precisely. If $s$ is the sum of the elements of a finite field then it's clear that $-s=s$. Hence $s=0$, except when that doesn't follow...

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I think the above now works.

Comment: Do you mean $n^{k-1}$?

Comment: Yes, I do. Woops.

Comment: Does this result also hold for any subspace of the vectoe space?

Comment: No, since the $k=1$ case can be realized by looking at a subspace.

Comment: How about for $k \geq 2$?

Comment: The sum of the vectors over the field $\Bbb{F}_4=\{0,1,\alpha,\alpha^2=\alpha+1\}$ is certainly zero even when  $k=1$ The same holds for bigger fields of characteristic two. $\Bbb{F}_2, k=1,$ is the only exception.